# socketio net::ERR_ABORTED 404 (Not Found)

Tags: javascript, express, socket.io

I've recently been learning about socket.IO. 
I've hosted a static directory "Public" using express, and i imported socketio into the index.html.

```
<script src="../node_modules/socket.io/client-dist/socket.io.js"></script>
```

The browser will report an error:

```
GET http://127.0.0.1:3000/node_modules/socket.io/client-dist/socket.io.js net::ERR_ABORTED 404 (Not Found)
```

But I modified it this way：

```
<script src="/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>
```

It works well!

[Here is the folder directory structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EQR81.png)

But the Public directory **doesn't have any other js files**,

So, where does it come from ?